# Copy values from cells from one sheet to another with MATCH and INDEX

Tags: excel, data-management, excel-match

**Sheet 1:**

- Taxon names in column B

[image]

**Sheet 2:**

- Taxon names in column A (range defined with the name "Taxon"; A:A)
- Names of the parameters in columns C through L (range defined with the name "FeedingType"; C3:L3)
- Values linked to the taxa in columns C through L (range defined with the name
  "IndexArea"; C4:L1248)

[image]

*Nature of data:* Taxon names on sheet 1 & 2 are not ordered in the same manner, and the taxon names on sheet 1 is a subset of taxa names of sheet 2.

**What I want done:** I want to copy the values linked to taxa from columns C through L in sheet 2 to the same taxa in sheet 1 in the columns K through T.

So, if I have a "Hydra viridissima (Sheet 2, A6) somewhere in sheet 1, it should bring the values "5" (Sheet 2, J6 under "pre") and "5" (Sheet 2, L6 under "oth") to their respective cells in Sheet 1, which in this case would be in columns R and T.

**What I have tried:** Went through a tutorial and thought I had it with:

***=INDEX(IndexArea,MATCH(B2,Taxon,0),MATCH($K$1,FeedingType,0))***

It's not working, though it does identify when things are not matching exactly (#N/B).

I tried to add sheet2! in the formula in reference to names assigned to the ranges like this: ***=INDEX(Sheet2!IndexArea,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!Taxon,0),MATCH($K$1,Sheet2!FeedingType,0))***, but gives the same error.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula treats *Taxon*, *FeedingType* and *IndexArea* as defined names but your narrative doesn't mention them being assigned defined names. Try it as row and column references.

```
' in US-EN
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$M, MATCH($B2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0), MATCH(K$1, Sheet2!$B$3:$M$3, 0))
' should the *FeedingType* come from column J?
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$M, MATCH($B2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0), MATCH($J2, Sheet2!$B$3:$M$3, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did name the ranges this, I just call it labeling. I'll edit the question and try out your formula.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I'm wondering why it wouldn't work with defining names like I did (tried that again). Also I am wondering why to set the range from the index to $B:$M and not $C:$L and if it would work with defined names if I set the IndexArea to $B:$M.

Comment: The $B:$M needs to match the $B$3:$M$3 to return the correct column. Defined names should work but I would need to see the range definition of each name to determine why they didn't work out.

Comment: Right, I see with the B:M, I get that now. The ranges for the definitions are: "Taxon"; A:A, "FeedingType"; C3:L3, "IndexArea"; C4:L1248 (guessing that could be $C:$L as well, in case I add stuff).

Comment: If Taxon is A:A then IndexArea needs to be C:L otherwise the result will be 3 rows down from what you want. IOW, The result from looking at all of column A will return the result **within** C4:L1248, a 6 would be row 9.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you very much for your education, sir!